# Sum of recursive tree in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

have a tree structure that looks like this:

```
                                 root
                   A                               B
          A1           A2                     B1        B2
      A1.1  A1.2      A2.1                   B1.1
```

the table looks something like this:

```
id | name |value | parent_id
1    root   null    null
2    A      null    1
3    B      null    1    
4    A1     null    2
5    A1.1   2       4
6    A1.2   3       4
7    A2     null    2
8    A2.1   5       7
9    B1     null    3
10   B2     1       3
11   B1.1   10      9   
.........................
```

All the non leaf nodes must contain the sum of their children, not only the root node. For example, this is how my desired output looks like:

```
id | name |value | parent_id
1    root   21      null
2    A      10      1
3    B      11      1    
4    A1     5       2
5    A1.1   2       4
6    A1.2   3       4
7    A2     5       2
8    A2.1   5       7
9    B1     10      3
10   B2     1       3
11   B1.1   10      9
```

how can i achieve this with a fast Postgres query

Comment: leaf nodes contain values and the parent nodes contain null at the beginning on must only contain the sum of their children.

Comment: @forpas oh my bad, B2 contains 1 initially. it was a typo on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE in the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t
SET "value" = c.value
FROM (
  WITH RECURSIVE cte AS(
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.value, t1.parent_id
    FROM tablename t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.name, c.value, t.parent_id
    FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c 
    ON c.parent_id = t.id
  )
  SELECT id, SUM("value") "value"
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY id
) c 
WHERE c.id = t.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2b66e72f17083e3dc3f13fcdb8205b4b).

Comment: works like a charm! thanks a lot for your help! 
if you don't mind me asking , what's the purpose of this line : 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.id)

Comment: @blablablabla in this part of the recursive cte I select all the leaf nodes which are the rows for which there is no other other row (NOT EXISTS) with parent_id their id.

Comment: i noticed that when i change the values inside children nodes, the query won't work correctly anymore as it'll display the old sum calculated from the old children values. why is that?

Comment: @blablablabla what do you mean? The values in the leaf nodes can be any values. The code does not work only for the specific values in your sample data.

Comment: never mind I found my silly mistake, sorry to bother you mate

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(id, name, val, p) as (
   select t.id, t.name, t.value, '.'||(select t1.id from tbl t1 where t1.parent_id is null)||'.'||t.id||'.' from tbl t where t.parent_id = (select t1.id from tbl t1 where t1.parent_id is null)
   union all
   select t.id, t.name, t.value, c.p||t.id||'.' from cte c join tbl t on c.id = t.parent_id
)
select t.id, sum(case when c.val is null then 0 else c.val end) from tbl t 
join cte c on c.p like '%.'||t.id||'.%' group by t.id order by t.id
```

---

To update your original table with the summed child node values, you can use a subquery in `update`:

```
update tbl set value = t1.val from (
   select t.id tid, sum(case when c.val is null then 0 else c.val end) val from tbl t 
   join cte c on c.p like '%.'||t.id||'.%' group by t.id) t1 
where t1.tid = id
```

Comment: nice! this is working so far! I'm looking to update the values inside the the table instead of having them maintain their original null value ( so how can i integrate update in this command?).
Also , i'm assuming this won't work once the original values have been changed (not NULL) anymore, is there a way to make this work even when the values inside parents are not null ?

Comment: @blablablabla Please see my recent edit.