Aggregate query on a tree implementation as a relation (sql table)
Given the following tree structure in a SQL table, and assuming the data is consistent (there are no rows with the same name, but different parents):
| name | parent | value |
|------|--------|-------|
| a    | null   |    10 |
| b    | a      |    15 |
| b    | a      |     4 |
| c    | a      |    15 |
| d    | a      |    10 |
| e    | b      |     5 |
| f    | b      |     5 |
| g    | null   |    20 |

I am looking for a query to sum up all sub-categories of a given node, like this:
| name | parent | value |
|------|--------|-------|
| a    | null   |    64 |
| b    | a      |    29 |
| c    | a      |    15 |
| d    | a      |    10 |
| e    | b      |     5 |
| f    | b      |     5 |
| g    | null   |    20 |

So, I can make only the first level of summation, and I can think of joining this to table itself on parent and and sum again... but I am looking for a solution for trees of unspecified depth. For the level 1 I have for example:
SELECT
    NAME,
    PARENT,
    SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM
    TEST
GROUP BY
    NAME,
    PARENT
ORDER BY
    NAME ASC;


Please tag your RDBMS, see here why that's important: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983767/sum-of-recursive-tree-in-postgres

There are also things like pgrouting and apache AGE that offer various well tested and highly optimised implementations of graph processing algorithms. If you prefer typing out your own, one-off implementation with a recursive CTE, make sure to take a look at cycle detection clause.

First, consolidate source table for (name,parent).
Then recursive collect all childs for every row.
See simple example
with  recursive 
 gr as(select name,parent,sum(amount) amount
      from test group by name,parent)
,r as(
  select 1 lvl,name root,parent,name child,0::bigint total,amount
  from gr
union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,r.root,r.parent,t.name child,r.total+t.amount,t.amount
  from r inner join gr t on t.parent=r.child
 )
 select root,parent,sum(amount)total
 from r
 group by root,parent
 order by root




name
parent
total




a
null
64


b
a
29


c
a
15


d
a
10


e
b
5


f
b
5


g
null
20



Test data:
create table test(name varchar(1),parent varchar(1), amount int);
insert into test14 values 
('a',null, 10),
('b','a', 15),
('b','a', 4),
('c','a', 15),
('d','a', 10),
('e','b', 5),
('f','b', 5),
('g',null, 20);

